# Applying multiple filters on html table (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two filters I would like to be applied together to a HTML table.  One is a checkbox that will hide rows that contain 'No Ratings'.  Another is a text filter that filters(hide/show) the rows as a user types in text.   Here is the code for the two filters

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#hideRows').change(function () {
        $('#indexTable tr:contains("No Ratings")').toggle(!this.checked);
    })

    $("#filterRow").keyup(function () {
        var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

        $("#indexTable tr").each(function (index) {
            if (!index) return;
            $(this).find("td.searchable").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
                var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
                $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
                return not_found;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to get these filters to work together, instead of independently.  For example, if a user checks the hideRows checkbox, the text filter will only filter through rows with the first filter applied, and vice-versa.  I've seen creating a master filter function maybe the solution, but I'm having trouble trying to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#hideRows').change(function () {
      var isChecked = !this.checked;

      $("#indexTable tr td:contains('No Ratings')").each(function(index, element){
          $(this).parent("tr").toggleClass("hide");
      });
  });

  $("#filterRow").keyup(function () {
      var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

      $("#indexTable tr").not(".hide").each(function (index) {
          if (!index) return;
          $(this).find("td.searchable").each(function () {
              var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
              var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
              $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
              return not_found;
          });
      });
  });


});
```

```css
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="indexTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Fruit</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="searchable">Apple</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="searchable">Banana</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Yellow</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="searchable">Orange</td>
        <td>No Ratings</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="searchable">Grape</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="searchable">Berry</td>
        <td>No Ratings</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="hideRows"> hideRows

<input type="text" name="" id="filterRow" placeholder="filter">
```

Comment: Hello, so the text filter seems to be working but the hideRows checkbox does not seem to do anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I tried the code.  The function for hideRows does not work unless your remove the $("#filterRow").keyup(); // or masterFilter(); section.  But if you remove, again it acts as independent filters

Comment: Why hideRows doesn't work? if there is a js error please put it here.

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in the console.  When I check the hideRows checkbox, it does nothing.

Comment: Please see the following jsfiddle for an example.  https://jsfiddle.net/13ozjrkm/.
The filterRows textbox is working correctly, but the hideRows is not.  When hideRows is checked, I want the filter to only search the rows that are shown.

Comment: Replace hideRow change event. answer updated, checkout the full working example above.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the help but I am still not getting the functionality desired.  For example, click the hiderows checkbox and search the letter 'e'.   Orange and berry still show even though they have 'no ratings'.  Or if you check the hide checkbox and type into the filter and delete, you see all rows again.